# How to use models variable as url?

Tags: django

In my models.py file i made a variable called hero_name. For instance, if the hero name is Bart, I want the url to be ./heroes/Bart

> urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<str:hero_name>/', views.heropage, name='heropage'),
]
```

> views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Heroes

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'heroes/index.html')

def heropage(request, hero_name):
    get_object_or_404(Heroes, pk=hero_name)
    return render(request, 'heroes/heropage.html')
```

> models.py

```
from django.db import models



class Heroes(models.Model):
    hero_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to replace your implementation of `get_object_or_404` with one that gets the object based on `hero_name` and not `pk`, since in your model, `hero_name` is not your primary key.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what you are asking. But you certainly need to use the relevant field to query the object, and pass the result to the template:

```
hero = get_object_or_404(Heroes, hero_name=hero_name)
return render(request, 'heroes/heropage.html', {"hero": hero})
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the field you want to primary_key.

```
class Heroes(models.Model):
    hero_name = models.CharField(primary_key=True)
```